# When working with socket library in python,why am I getting this error?

Tags: sockets

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Most probable cause is that your target is not `listening` .

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused occurs due to some issues.
1- Firewall- please make sure that both machines have a disabled firewall.
2- SocketServer- your socket server may be closed or disposed of.
3- Antivirus - make you disabled all antivirus because antivirus always blocks the NAT traffic.